# Filtering and transforming a collection using Google Guava

Tags: java, collections, guava, jodatime

Imagine the following object

```
class Trip {
  String name;
  int numOfTravellers;
  DateMidnight from;
  DateMidnight too;
}
```

I have written a manual recursive filter and transform method in java. However, I think this could be written more eloquently using Google Guava.

Can someone help me out and tell me how I can rewrite this to make more readable?

*Basically what this method does, is locating equal entries, and combining the ones that are equal by altering the date fields*

```
List<Trip> combineEqual(List<Trip> list) {
        int n = list.size() - 1;
        for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = n; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (shouldCombineEqual(list.get(i), list.get(j))) {
                    Trip combined = combine(list.get(i), list.get(j));
                    list.remove(i);
                    list.remove(j);
                    list.add(Math.min(i, j), combined);
                    return combineEqual(liste);
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }


private boolean shouldCombineEqual(Trip a, Trip b) {
    return shouldCombineWith(a, b) || shouldCombineWith(b, a);
}

private boolean shouldCombineWith(Trip a, Trip b) {
    return a.too() != null
            && a.too().plusDays(1).equals(b.from)
            && areEqual(a, b);
}

private boolean areEqual(Trip a, Trip b) {
    return equal(a.name,b.name) && equal(a.numOfTravellers, b.numOfTravellers);
}

private boolean equal(Object a, Object b) {
    return a == null && b == null || a != null && a.equals(b);
}

private Trip combineEqual(Trip a, Trip b) {
    Trip copy = copy(a); //Just a copy method
    if (a.from.isAfter(b.from)) {
        Trip tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    } // a is now the one with the earliest too date
    copy.from = a.from;
    copy.too = b.too;
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: I think the combination of iteration and recursion certainly reduces the readability. May be you can use a map here with just one for-loop. Every element in the list either goes into the map or gets combined with a value in the map.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Guava can help much here. There's a lot you can improve without it:

Create a `TripKey {String name; int numOfTravellers;}`, define `equals`, and use it instead of your misnamed `areEqual`. Split your trips into lists by their keys - here `ListMultimap<TripKey, Trip>` can help.

For each key, sort the corresponding list according to `from`. Try to combine each trip with all following trips. If it gets combined, restart the inner loop only. This should be already much clearer (and faster) than your solution... so I stop here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use a HashSet.

First define equals and hashcode in your trip object. Add the first list to the set. Then iterate through the second list checking if a matching trip is already in the set. Something like:

```
    public static Set<Trip> combineEquals(List<Trip> 11, List<Trip> 12) {
    Set<Trip> trips = new HashSet<>(11);
    for ( Trip t: 12) {
        if ( trips.contains(t)) {
            // combine whats in the set with t
        } else {
            trips.add(t);
        }
    }

    return trips;
```